# How to make Pydantic raise an exception right away

Tags: python, pydantic

I wrote a Pydantic model to validate API payload.

The payload has 2 attributes `emailId` as `list` and `role` as `str`

```
{
    "emailId": [], 
    "role":"Administrator"
}
```

I need to perform two validation on attribute email -

1. `emailId` must not be empty.
2. `emailId` must not contain emails from x, y, z domains.

Hence to accomplish this I wrote 2 validation methods for `emailId` as shown below -

```
class PayloadValidator(BaseModel):

    emailId: List[str]
    role: str

    @validator("emailId")
    def is_email_list_empty(cls, email):
        if not email_id:
            raise ValueError("Email list is empty.")
        return email_id

    @validator("emailId")
    def valid_domains(cls, emailId):
        pass
```

The problem here is that if the `emailId` list is empty then the validators does not `raise` `ValueError` right away. It waits for all the validation method to finish execution and this is causing some serious problems to me.

Is there a way I can make it happen?

Comment: use `pre` for this (`def is_email_list_empty(cls, email, pre=True)`) to do the list validation first

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. It is still executing `valid_domain()`. I want it to raise the error right away and terminate the further validations.

Comment: Couldn't you merge the two validators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have checks, the failure of which should interrupt the further validation, then put them in the `pre=True` [root validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators). Because *field validation will not occur if `pre=True` root validators raise an error*.

For example:

```
class PayloadValidator(BaseModel):

    emailId: List[str]
    role: str

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def root_validate(cls, values):
        if not values['emailId']:
            raise ValueError("Email list is empty.")
        return values

    @validator("emailId")
    def valid_domains(cls, emailId):
        return emailId
```