# Stop Execution on first validation error and return in Pydantic?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pydantic

I am using `Pydantic` models for schema validation.
`Pydantic` checks all the input fields in the schema and returns all the error(s) which takes a lot of time.

Let's say I have 1000s of `Class A` object defined in a List and `Pydantic` checks all of them if they have proper field assigned or not and returns an error if a particular field is missing in all of those objects, 1000s time.

Is it possible to stop checking on first validationerror from `Pydantic` and return that particular error in `ValiationError`?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible in any straightforward way. But you can use pre root validator and validate the list items yourself. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536863/how-to-make-pydantic-raise-an-exception-right-away/69538066#69538066)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, So what about extra fields, does `root_validator` with `pre=False` has access to extra fields as well? @alex_noname