# Pydantic validator does not work as expected

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have recently found the power of Pydantic validators and proceeded to uses them in one of my personal projects.

However, I've encountered a problem: the failure of one validator does not stop the execution of the following validators, resulting in an Exception.

```
class Field(BaseModel):
    name: constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    type: constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    length: Optional[int]
    nullable: bool


class Unique(BaseModel):
    name: constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    unique_fields: List[constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)]


class Resource(BaseModel):
    name: constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    table_name: constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    fields: List[Field]
    primary_key: constr(min_length=1, max_length=32)
    uniques: Optional[List[Unique]]

    @validator('name')
    def resource_name_must_be_pure_string(cls, v):
        if not v.isalpha():
            raise ValueError(ONLY_ALPHA_ERR.format("Resource name"))
        return v

    @validator('table_name')
    def table_name_must_be_pure_string(cls, v):
        if not v.isalpha():
            raise ValueError(ONLY_ALPHA_ERR.format("Table name"))
        return v

    @validator('fields', pre=True)
    def field_name_must_be_pure_string(cls, v):
        fieldnames = [field["name"] for field in v]
        print(fieldnames)
        for fieldname in fieldnames:
            if not fieldname.replace('_', '').isalpha():
                print('was here')
                raise ValueError("A field's name can only contain alphabetic characters and '_'.")
        return v

    @validator('primary_key')
    def primary_key_must_be_in_fields(cls, v, values):
        fieldnames = [field.name for field in values["fields"]]

        if v not in fieldnames:
            raise ValueError(f"Primary key `{v}` should be one of the input fields.")
        return v
```

The method **field_name_must_be_pure_string** prints "was here", therefore the ValueError exception should have been raised, but the execution proceeds to the next validator, which would be **primary_key_must_be_in_fields**, that fails because the preceding list of fields was invalid.

What would be the solution to this corner case?

Comment: I think this is not possible and you will always get back all validation results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840042/stop-execution-on-first-validation-error-and-return-in-pydantic. To be more explicit on that, you could do a try: fields = values["fields"] except KeyError: raise ValueError("Issue with fields") but not sure if that is helpful

Comment: I thought the raised exception would be reflected in the FastAPI response before the following exception occurs (which shows 500 Server Error). Indeed, one way would be to wrap the following validations that depend on the "fields" member in a try|except block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, but managed to avoid getting a crash by using the following:

```
@validator('primary_key')
def primary_key_must_be_in_fields(cls, v, values):
    if "fields" not in values:
        return

    fieldnames = [field.name for field in values["fields"]]

    if v not in fieldnames:
        raise ValueError(f"Primary key `{v}` should be one of the input fields.")
    return v
```

It took a while to realise that Pydantic will do all validations and will not stop at first exception.